# subset rows in dataframe using combinations of conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame:

```
table = structure(list(Plot = 1:10, Sp1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                    0L, 1L, 0L), Sp2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               Sp3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Sp4 = c(0L, 
                                                                        1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                  -10L))
```

0 represents a species (Sp) being absent from a plot. 1 represents a species being present.

First, I want to subset my data frame so that only plots with Sp1 or Sp3 or Sp4 remain. This can be done easily with `filter` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
reduced_table <- table %>% filter(table$Sp1 == 1 |table$Sp3 == 1 | table$Sp4 == 1)
```

But, what if I want to reduce the table so that only plots that have any combination of two of these species is present. For example plots with Sp1 & Sp3, or Sp1 and Sp4, or Sp3 and Sp4 would remain.

Can this be done eloquently like using `filter`? My real situation has many more species and therefore many more combinations so explicitly writing out the combinations is not ideal.

Comment: NOTE: Inside the dplyr functions, you don't need `data$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `if_any` with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
   filter(if_any(c(Sp1, Sp3, Sp4), ~ .== 1))
```

-output

```
#   Plot Sp1 Sp2 Sp3 Sp4
#1    1   0   1   1   0
#2    2   0   0   1   1
#3    3   1   1   1   1
#4    4   1   0   1   0
#5    5   0   0   1   1
#6    6   1   0   0   0
#7    7   0   1   1   0
#8    8   0   0   1   1
#9    9   1   0   0   1
```

---

Or using a `combn`ation of columns

```
library(purrr)
combn(c("Sp1", "Sp3", "Sp4"), 2, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  map_dfr( ~ table %>%
         filter(if_all(.x, ~ . == 1))) %>%
  distinct
```

---

If the intention is to do filtering on pairwise column checks, use `combn` from `base R`

```
subset(table, Reduce(`|`, combn(c("Sp1", "Sp3", "Sp4"), 2, 
  FUN = function(x) rowSums(table[x] == 1) == 2, simplify = FALSE)))
```

Comment: The desired output should only include plots where Sp1 & Sp3 are present, or where Sp1 & Sp4 are present, or where Sp3 and Sp4 are present. Therefore, Plot 1, Plot 6, and Plot 7 should not be in the resulting data frame.

Comment: @nateroe this code is based on your code in the post `table %>% filter(table$Sp1 == 1 |table$Sp3 == 1 | table$Sp4 == 1)`

Comment: thanks! That is a better way to do that part. Any idea on: But, what if I want to reduce the table so that only plots that have any combination of two of these species is present. For example plots with Sp1 & Sp3, or Sp1 and Sp4, or Sp3 and Sp4 would remain.

Comment: @nateroe I guess you are looking for pairwise operation i.e. `nm1 <- combn(c("Sp1", "Sp3", "Sp4"), 2, simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: @nateroe do you want the output as in the update

Comment: yes, if you could provide a final solution, I will accept.

Comment: @nateroe you meant the subset solution is correct, but you want a dplyr one, right?

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. Could you explain how the ```.x``` works in ```filter(if_all(.x, ~ . == 1))```?